# Soap-запрос через curl не работает

Tags: http, api, curl, soap

Пытаюсь сходить на сервак при помощи curl. Но получаю от вервера 400. При этом, коллега ходить из win с помощью linqpad и получает корректный ответ.

Команда:

```
curl 
-X POST 
--data '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetContractList xmlns="http://domain.domain.domain/">
      <login>user</login>
      <password>pwd</password>
    </GetContractList>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
' 
-H "Host: host.host.ru" 
-H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" 
-H "Content-Length: length" 
-H 'SOAPAction: "http://domain.domain.domain/method"' 
host.host.ru/path/service.asmx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, в API был указано неверное описание тела и header`а. Привожу пример верного:

```
curl 
-X POST 
--data '
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="http://Ocourier.Services.Manifest/" xmlns:tns="http://Ocourier.Services.Manifest/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <GetContractList xmlns="http://Ocourier.Services.Manifest/">
            <login>ApiUserIR</login>
            <password>ApiUserIR</password>
        </GetContractList>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
'
-H "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://Ocourier.Services.Manifest/GetContractList"
```

В причинах не разобрался. Подозреваю, что это может быть связано со особенностями реализации API.